# How to schedule and trigger a delay between publication pages in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I currently work on a recipes web application, where each user have the possibility to like a recipe. A recipe is composed by severals steps.

When an user like a recipe, he is supposed to receive the first step of the recipe. He can see it appear on the steps/index.html.erb page. The next ones are not visible yet.
Then, when he opens it, (recipes/:recipe_id/steps/1/show.html.erb), it displays the first step and, in the same time, triggers a time interval (configurable), before the apparition of the second step, and so on until the last step of the recipe.

The wait and the apparition of a step just have to occur once. When a step is loaded, it always appears on the list without waiting.
To schedule this, someone explains me to use ajax requests. But I did not well describe my problem and working on it, I encounted difficulties… Now I doubt on the structure of all and feel a bit lost!

If you have any idea, 
in advance thanks  a lot ;)

Here my code :

Models :

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user
has_many :steps
has_many :favorites
has_many :favorited_by_users, :through => :favorites, :source => 'user'

class Step < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :recipe
end

class Favorite < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :recipe
belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
has_many :recipes
has_many :favorites
has_many :favorite_recipes, :through => :favorites, :source => 'recipe’

devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

In my Step Controller i have :

```
  def index
  @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:recipe_id]) 
  @steps = @recipe.steps
  end
```

Thanks!!

Comment: To clarify, what you want is something like this? 1) User clicks Like button on a particular recipe 2) User sees Step1 of the recipe on the page 3) After a few seconds "delay", the page automatically redirects to Step2 which then displays it on the page 3) After a few seconds "delay" again, the page redirects to Step3 and display it accordingly 4) Repeat 2) and 3) until no more Steps left

Comment: Hi @Jay-Ar Polidario thanks for your response! :) Regarding the problem, it is not exactly that. User clicks on Like button on a particular recipe. Just after, he sees the link to acceed to this first step of this recipe. And it is when he clicks on this "open button" that the time delay starts. And at the end of this delay, he sees the click for the second step... etc.

Comment: what do you mean by "acceed"? You said: "And at the end of this delay, he sees the click for the second step", so does that mean Step2 is not shown on the page, but that only the "open button" links of the Step1, Step2, Step3, and so on appears on the page? So essentially the page doesn't change? but that only the links appear one by one after each delay?

Comment: Analysing your question, is this what you intend? 1) User likes a Recipe 2) User clicks the Recipe (somewhere) which opens up Step1 3) User sees Step1 4) After some "delay", Step2 link is now visible on that Step1 page 5) But if the user navigated out of the page / reload the page, then the user needs to wait again for that some "delay" in order for the Step2 link to appear. 6) repeat these for all steps

Comment: @Jay-Ar Polidario sorry for my english, it is pretty bad and not so clear! in fact. When i said "acceed" i meant "display". In my logic, and i dont know if it is possible, it is : 1) User like a recipe (button on page recipes/id, recipes#show). 2) redirection to recipe steps index page (/recipes/:recipe_id/steps. 3) in the step index, just step 1 displayed. 4) click on step link and 2 things happen. 5.a) open step/id page. 5b) trigger a countdown before the apparition of next step... about the apparition it is the link + the content... I hope it is better explaination ;) thank for your help!

Comment: No worries! :) What does this mean? "apparition of next step" in step 5b)? Does it mean a redirect to the next step? Or does it just show on the current page (without reloading the page)? if it is just shown on the current page, does it replace Step1 content, or if not does it get appended below the Step1 content on the page?

Comment: in fact, "apparition of the next step" just means its visibility... or availability. the 5b) can be reformulate like : "trigger a countdown, and at the end of the delay, the next step link is available on the index step page (index.html.erb). and by clicking it, the user is linked to the content "recipes/:recipe_id/steps/:step_id. It is not exactly an "apparition" because for the user, nothing happen. He can remains on the previous step page and read it normally. but if he returns to the steps index, he will notice the "aparition" of the next step link and will be able to click on it

Comment: Ahh I see. Okay I think I'm getting it now :) I'll write up the simplest solution I can think of.

Comment: Do you have jquery included?

Comment: ok thanks! yes i have jquery included ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a place to store data that will determine if a user has already read a step or not yet. So, we'll add a new "join-table" between `User` and `Step` model.

**bash / terminal:**

```
rails generate model steps_user step:belongs_to user:belongs_to is_read:boolean
```

*Recommended: change the migration file generated for above, to have `default: false, null: false` for `is_read`*

**app/config/routes.rb**

```
resources :steps do
  resources :steps_users, only: [] do
    put :create_or_update, on: :collection, as: 'create_or_update_steps_user'
  end
end
```

**app/controllers/steps_users_controller.rb**

```
class StepsUsersController < ApplicationController
  def create_or_update
    @step = Step.find(params[:step_id])
    @steps_user = @step.steps_users.find_or_initialize_by(user: current_user)

    # you can further refactor this to use `save()` and not `save!()`
    # but for simplicity, I'll just use this to raise exception when there is a validation error
    if @steps_user.save!(steps_user_params)
      render status: :ok
    end
  end

  private 

  def steps_user_params
    params.require(:steps_user).permit(:is_read)
  end
end
```

**app/models/step.rb**

```
class Step < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :steps_users

  def previous_step
    # you might want to update this as I do not know if you have your own Step attribute that determines the "order" of the Steps
    recipe.steps.order(id: :desc).where('id < ?', id).first
  end
  # ...
```

**app/controllers/steps_controller.rb:**

```
class StepsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @step = Step.find(params[:id])

    # add some authorization here to prevent anyone from reading this step unless they have already read the previous steps (example code is below)
    # if @step.previous_step && !@step.previous_step.is_read?
    #   render status: :forbidden
    # end
  end
  # ...
```

**app/views/steps/show.html.erb:**

```
<script type='text/javasript'>
  $(function() {
    var delay = 30000; // 30 seconds

    var updateStepsUserAsRead = function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<%= j create_or_update_steps_user_path(step_id: @step.id) %>',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        headers: {
          'X-CSRF-Token': Rails.csrfToken()
        },
        data: {
          _method: 'put',
          steps_user: {
            is_read: true
          }
        }
      })
    }

    setTimeout(updateStepsUserAsRead, delay);
  })
</script>

...
```

> Above JS script will mark `is_read` to be `true` for the current_user's `steps_user` record

**app/views/steps/index.html.erb**

```
<% @steps.each do |step| %>
  <% if !step.previous_step || (step.previous_step && step.previous_step.is_read?) %>
    <%= link_to 'Step #', step # <<<<< update this %> 
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thank you so much !! I will try this! But thank you for your time and your work !!

Comment: No problem! :) Good luck! Let me know if something doesn't work!

Comment: Hello @Jay-Ar Polidario, thanks again. I worked on what you did since yesterday. And I wonder something : do I have to add some code on my recipe page (show.html.erb), on the button like in order to launch the process you coded ? Just answer if you have the time, no worries if you cannot ;)

Comment: You don't have anything to do with the "Like" recipe button. You already have this implemented right? So what happens is that 1) User clicks Like recipe button, then 2) User is redirected to recipes/:reciped_id/steps 3) then here in this steps page, the different Step 1, Step 2, Step 3, ... links are already there (see my app/views/steps/index.html.erb above).

Comment: Yes I already implemented the like button on the recipe page, and it adds recipe to favorites user. Ok thanks, and just a last question, as for the script tag you wrote : "app/views/steps/show.index.html.erb" it is for both ? show.html.erb and show.html.erb ? thks!

Comment: oh sorry about that, I just updated it now. It's only for "show" :)

Comment: hi @Jay-Ar Polidario! I worked on your code since you posted it! ;) Everything seems good excepeted the ajax part on the step show view. I feel a bit stuck because rails always return " NoMethodError in Steps#show" and points out this line <%= j create_or_update_sequences_user_path(sequence_id: @sequence.id) %>'. Do you think there is a problem ? ;) THKS!

Comment: if it doesn't work, can you try running `bundle exec rake routes`? and then check the correct name? Probably my named `create_or_update_steps_user_path` route name is wrong

Comment: Oh yes you're right! ;) it tells me the route : "create_or_update_steps_user_recipe_step_steps_users lool!